# Stack Exchange Data Explorer was not really updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer page claims that the “English Language & Usage” data was last updated on March 21, but the data is much older than that.

One example of query where this is highlighted: https://data.stackexchange.com/english/qe/208/keystrokes-per-rep-point returns reputation for top users that is much lower than its [actual value](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). For example, JSBangs has 8527 rep, but SEDE reports 5980.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data should be up to date now ... my import process runs in 2 phases:

1. I export all public data to the current db (separate db per exported set)
2. I detach all the dbs that were exported and attach them to a sandboxed db.

Step 2 did not run.

Comment: No, sorry, still not up to date.

Comment: Eh, just give us direct access to the production DB.  You can trust *us* can't you?

Comment: OK, now it is up to date.

Comment: @Adam ... you have no ideas what amount of beatings I would suffer if we leaked our votes table :)

Comment: @waffles Oh but it would be fun to find out!  I'll get the bactine, you write the proxy...

Comment: Would the beatings be televised? Or at least podcast?

Answer (score 2):

Agreed: https://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1132/last-vote-by-date