# Pretty pretty please, can you update the SEDE data? (not just the date)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

So, [after asking for a SEDE update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90390), we got one — sort of: **the date was changed, but it's still the old data**. [Same as last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84376/stack-exchange-data-explorer-was-not-really-updated).
 Can we, pretty pretty please, get a real SEDE update?

Comment: Huh. So I *wasn't* seeing things when the results were turning up values that seemed old.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

big oops, sorry ... will change the export routine to catch this.

For the record I need to add:

```
truncate table CachedResults
truncate table CachedPlans
```

To the end of my export routine.